# Named List To/From Data.Frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm looking for a quick way to get back and forth between a list of the following format:

```
$`a`
  [1] 1 2 3
$`b`
  [1] 4 5 6
```

to/from a data.frame of the following format:

```
   name x
 1    a 1
 2    a 2
 3    a 3
 4    b 4
 5    b 5
 6    b 6
```

(Don't really care what the names of the columns are, in this case.)

Here's the data frame used above in R-format:

```
df <- data.frame(name=c(rep("a",3),rep("b",3)), x=c(1:3,4:6))
```

Again, I'm looking for two separate operations: one to convert the above data.frame to a list, and another to convert it back to a data.frame.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use `stack` and `unstack` in base R:

```
x <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=4:6)

x
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

Use `stack` to from wide to tall, i.e. stack the vectors on top of one another.

```
y <- stack(x)
y
  values ind
1      1   a
2      2   a
3      3   a
4      4   b
5      5   b
6      6   b
```

Use `unstack` to do the reverse.

```
unstack(y)
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

---

If your data structure is more complicated than you described, `stack` and `unstack` may no longer be suitable. In that case you'll have to use `reshape` in base R, or `melt` and `dcast` in package `reshape2`.

Answer (score 17):

Another option is `enframe` from `tibble`

```
library(tidyverse)
enframe(lst1) %>%
   unnest
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(a=1:3, b=4:6)
```

Answer (score 11):

Maybe something like:

```
X <- split(df$x, df$name)
data.frame(name = rep(names(X), sapply(X, length)), 
    x=do.call('c', X))
```

**EDIT:** *I decided to combine Andrie and I's solution into one that appears to be exactly what the OP asked for fairly simple.  That being said I don't quite understand a situation where I would treat the data this way instead of how Andrie did it since a data frame is a list of equal length vectors anyway.*

```
# Your data set
df <- data.frame(name=c(rep("a",3),rep("b",3)), x=c(1:3,4:6))

# converting it to list of vectors
X <- split(df[, 2], df[, 1])
# converting it to a dataframe
Y <- stack(X)[, 2:1]; names(Y) <- names(df)

# Take Y and feed it back to these lines to show it 
# switches back and forth
(X <- split(Y[, 2], Y[, 1]))
Y <- stack(X)[, 2:1]; names(Y) <- names(df);Y
```

Comment: +1 I was thinking maybe `melt(as.data.frame(...),value.name = 'x',variable.name = 'name')` to go back to the data frame.

Comment: One should note that split reorders the data frame as it builds a factor of the second vector. See also [Creating a named list from two vectors (names, values)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842705/creating-a-named-list-from-two-vectors-names-values) for a solution using `mapply`.

Answer (score 10):

I wish to make the hopefully non-trivial remark that @Tyler Rinker's suggestion

```
X <- split(df$x, df$name)
```

can be done more generally with

```
X <- split(df, df$name)
```

@Tyler Rinker's `split()` explanation [matches the R cookbook](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/r/9780596809287/6dot1dot-splitting-a-vector-into-groups/id3392005)
specifying that a vector can be grouped, while in fact the entire dataframe can be grouped.  I would think that grouping the dataframe, not the vector, would be the more valuable tool (and in fact what brought me to this post).

```
(df <- data.frame(name=c(rep("a",3),rep("b",3), rep("c",3)), x=c(1:3,4:6, 7:9)))
(X <- split(df, df$name))
```

HTH.