# list of character vectors of unequal length to data.frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a named list that looks like this:

```
> head(pathways)
$<NA>
NULL
$`2`
[1] "hsa04610"
$`9`
[1] "hsa00232" "hsa00983" "hsa01100"
$`10`
[1] "hsa00232" "hsa00983" "hsa01100"
$<NA>
NULL
$<NA>
NULL
```

To describe it more formerly. The name of each list is an id number, and the entries of each element of the character vector that are elements of the list is another id number. I can filter out the `$<NA>` entries easily with `is.na()`, but then I want to change the rest so it would look like:

```
id   another_id
2    hsa04610   
9    hsa00232   
9    hsa00983   
9    hsa01100   
10   hsa00232  
10   hsa00983
10   hsa01100


> dput(test)
structure(list(`NA` = NULL, `2` = "hsa04610", `9` = c("hsa00232", 
"hsa00983", "hsa01100"), `10` = c("hsa00232", "hsa00983", "hsa01100"
), `NA` = NULL, `NA` = NULL), .Names = c(NA, "2", "9", "10", 
NA, NA))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It would help if you were to post the output from `dput(head(pathways))`.

Comment: So while waiting for answers, which wasn't long (cheers, btw) I continued to google and found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432993/named-list-to-from-data-frame 
which basically says I can use stack(pathways). Will this work? It seems to simple?

Comment: It did work on your test object. (without even removing the NA entries ...to my surprise.) Kudos on the googling, BTW.

Comment: Slightly embarrassed that I found immediately after posting the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I found another answer that seems to work.

`stack(pathways)`

This seems too easy, but oh well.

Comment: nice find. `stack` does what you'd expect `unsplit` to do.

Answer (score 2):

So if you have list `l` (after removing NA's), then:

```
another_id <- unlist(l)
id <- rep(names(l), unlist(lapply(l, length)))
data.frame(id, another_id, row.names=NULL)
```

will give the result.

Answer (score 2):

```
#sample data
pathways <- list(`1` = letters[1:3], `2` = LETTERS[4:5], `3` = 6:9, `4` = NULL)

#a solution
n <- vapply(pathways, length, integer(1))
id <- rep.int(names(pathways), n)
another_id <- unlist(pathways, use.names = FALSE)
data.frame(id = id, another_id = another_id)
```