# Creating a named list from two vectors (names, values)

Tags: r, list, constructor, lapply, named

Is there a way to use mapply on two vectors to construct a named list? The first vector would be of type `character` and contain the names used for the list while the second contains the values.

So far, the only solution I have is:

```
> dummyList = list()
> addToList <- function(name, value) {
+ dummyList[[name]] <- value
+ }
> mapply(addToList, c("foo", "bar"), as.list(c(1, 2))
$foo
`1`

$bar
`2`
```

This seems like a rather contrived solution, but I can't figure out how to do it otherwise. The problems I have with it are:

1. It requires the creation of `dummyList` even though `dummyList` is never changed and is an empty list after the call to `mapply`.
2. If the numeric vector, `c(1, 2)`, is not converted to a list, then the result of the call to `mapply` is a named vector of doubles.

To get around problem 2, I can always just call `mapply` on two vectors and then call `as.list` on the result, but it seems like there should be a way to directly create a list with the values being in a vector.

Comment: Related: Create a tibble (instead of a named list) directly in code, with attribute names and values side-by-side, as any language of 2020 should be able to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58427326/ ... proper in-code definitions of maps: it should not be hard.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You can use `setNames()`

```
setNames(as.list(c(1, 2)), c("foo", "bar"))
```

(for a list) or

```
setNames(c(1, 2), c("foo", "bar"))
```

(for a vector)

Answer (score 11):

What I propose is made in 2 steps, and it's quite straightforward, so maybe it's easier to understand:

```
test_list <- list(1, 2)
names(test_list) <- c("foo", "bar")
```

What @ben-bolker proposes works, but just wanted to share an alternative, in case you prefer it.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 9):

I share Ben's puzzlement about why you might want to do this, and his recommendation.

Just for curiosity's sake, there is a sort of "hidden" feature in `mapply` that will allow this:

```
x <- letters[1:2]
y <- 1:2
mapply(function(x,y) { y }, x, y, SIMPLIFY = FALSE,USE.NAMES = TRUE)
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2
```

Noting that the documentation for `USE.NAMES` says:

> USE.NAMES  logical; use names if the first ... argument has names, or
>   if it is a character vector, use that character vector as the names.

Comment: I don't think this is such a puzzling use case, just a degenerate one. I needed to combine two double arrays each with some kind of row.names column that didn't get automatically picked up by USE.NAMES, so I had to pass in row.names(x) manually as an argument to the function which doesn't get used: `f = function(n, x, y) { if (y > 0) { -1 * x } else { x } }; r = mapply(f, row.names(x), x, y, SIMPLIFY=F, USE.NAMES=T)`. A `data.frame(unlist(r))` finished the job. Thanks for pointing out this feature!