# merge two vectors using one as the header for the other

Tags: r

I have two vectors.

```
x <- c("a","b","c")
y <- c(NA, 1, NA)
```

I want to combine to get the following where x is the column heading:

```
  a  b   c
 NA  1  NA
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a named list from two vectors (names, values)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842705/creating-a-named-list-from-two-vectors-names-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can data frame the transpose of `y` and then use `x` to assign the column names.

```
df <- data.frame(t(y))
names(df) <- x

df
   a b  c
1 NA 1 NA
```

### Demo

Comment: Tim no need to convert to df

Comment: `x <- c("a","b","c")
    y <- c(NA, 1, NA)
    names(y) <- x`

Comment: @Hardikgupta I interpreted the phrase `column names` in the OP to mean that a data frame/table was wanted.  Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Or other option is `setNames(as.data.frame.list(y), x)`