# create a data-frame with the new column values being the names of a list

Tags: r, list, dplyr

Given the following unequal list :

```
lst <- list("es1-7"= c(1,2,3,4), "sa1-12"=c(3,4) , "ES8-13"= c(9,7,4,1,5,2))

> lst
$`es1-7`
[1] 1 2 3 4

$`sa1-12`
[1] 3 4

$`ES8-13`
[1] 9 7 4 1 5 2
```

I would like to create a data-frame like this:

```
 group     numbers
1  es1-7       1
2  es1-7       2
3  es1-7       3
4  es1-7       4
5 sa1-12       3
6    ...     ...
```

So in this case `names` of the list will be values of a new column called `group`and `numbers` will be the values of the list.

Solutions using `base` and `dplyr` are more than welcome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Named List To/From Data.Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432993/named-list-to-from-data-frame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `stack` from `base R` to create a two column data.frame

```
stack(lst)[2:1]
```

---

Or with `enframe`

```
library(tidyverse)
enframe(lst, name = "group", value = "numbers") %>%
    unnest
```

Comment: Love this `stack(lst)[2:1]`