# Creating a data frame out of a list of element with different length

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a with numerical elements of different length of the form

```
list1 <- 1 : 2
list2 <- 1 : 3
list3 <- c(10, 100)


mylist <- list(a = list1, b = list2, c = list3)
```

and I would like to transform it into a data frame like this one

```
# a 1
# a 2
# b 1
# b 2
# b 3
# c 10
# c 100
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: `stack(mylist)`

Comment: @akrun, I noticed that there was an error in the previous one. But thank you so much for both solutions: `expand.grid` is going to be useful. Thank you for the updated solution too.

Comment: Duplicate: [Named List To/From Data.Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432993/named-list-to-from-data-frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could directly apply `expand.grid` on a `list`

```
expand.grid(mylist)
```

---

Or with `expand_grid` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
expand_grid(!!!mylist)
```

---

For the updated dataset

```
library(tibble)
enframe(mylist) %>% 
  unnest(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to e.g. `expand.grid` using `lapply`

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(mylist$b, function(x) cbind(x, y = mylist$a))))
   x y
1  1 1
2  1 2
3  1 3
4  1 4
5  1 5
6  2 1
7  2 2
8  2 3
9  2 4
10 2 5
11 3 1
12 3 2
13 3 3
14 3 4
15 3 5
```